# Increase the performance of sort command on a multi-processor Sun Solaris box

Tags: performance-tuning, solaris-10, sort

I have a bunch of (rather large i.e. >100MB) comma separated files which needs sorting on 4 processor box with SunOS 5.10

Sort appears to run rather slow (minutes)

I am wondering if there is any way to speed things up, for example making use of more than one processor/core or perhaps by just using some clever sort options?

PS: I am using the entire line as a key so just `sort filename > filename.sorted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [need high performance /bin/sort; any suggestions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/164275/need-high-performance-bin-sort-any-suggestions/222727#222727)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the script I wrote for this purpose. On a 4 processor machine it improved the sort performance by 100% ! (Thanks Bash for the tip!)

```
#! /bin/ksh

MAX_LINES_PER_CHUNK=1000000
ORIGINAL_FILE=$1
SORTED_FILE=$2
CHUNK_FILE_PREFIX=$ORIGINAL_FILE.split.
SORTED_CHUNK_FILES=$CHUNK_FILE_PREFIX*.sorted

usage ()
{
     echo Parallel sort
     echo usage: psort file1 file2
     echo Sorts text file file1 and stores the output in file2
     echo Note: file1 will be split in chunks up to $MAX_LINES_PER_CHUNK lines
     echo  and each chunk will be sorted in parallel
}

# test if we have two arguments on the command line
if [ $# != 2 ]
then
    usage
    exit
fi

#Cleanup any lefover files
rm -f $SORTED_CHUNK_FILES > /dev/null
rm -f $CHUNK_FILE_PREFIX* > /dev/null
rm -f $SORTED_FILE

#Splitting $ORIGINAL_FILE into chunks ...
split -l $MAX_LINES_PER_CHUNK $ORIGINAL_FILE $CHUNK_FILE_PREFIX

for file in $CHUNK_FILE_PREFIX*
do
    sort $file > $file.sorted &
done
wait

#Merging chunks to $SORTED_FILE ...
sort -m $SORTED_CHUNK_FILES > $SORTED_FILE

#Cleanup any lefover files
rm -f $SORTED_CHUNK_FILES > /dev/null
rm -f $CHUNK_FILE_PREFIX* > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this script a while ago: [distsort.sh](http://bashcurescancer.com/sorting-large-files-faster-with-a-shell-script.html)

I don't remember  what I used it for or if it worked, so let me know if it works for you.